# Why qt webengine can't play youtube live video streams

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtwebengine

I was creating a simple webbrowser using webengine. I went to youtube and tried to play a live stream but failed. Same thing happens with every video which requires HTML5 video support in browsers. I didn't saw any recent problems which are identical to this. Qt says that webengine has HTML5 support from they released Qt5. Some old answers to same questions suggest them to compile qtwebengine your own. I tried several attempts and failed(may be my computer can't do the job). Some other say to enable proprietary plugins from the code. But in my case it too didn't work.

Running the code also logs an error  `WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.`

So this is my simple qml code.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    WebEngineView{
        anchors.fill:parent
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL53Y28Rp84"
    }
}
```

Qt version: 5.15.1(GNU Public License )

Installed using qt online installer.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely that - as the error in the console said - you haven't initialized the web engine. In your `main()`, you must call `QtWebEngine::initialize()` before you do any rendering. So your main function should look like this:

```
#include <QtWebEngine>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    (...)
}
```

As per the Qt documentation, the `initialize()` function makes sure that the OpenGL context can be shared between the GUI and the renderer process.
[Link to the Qt documentation.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine.html#initialize)

Comment: I added that before creation of QCoreApplication because it said it was going to depreciated  in future. Now it stopped showing that error but it didn't fix my problem of not having html5 video support.

Comment: Well, Qt has an example where they embed a YouTube video, but it’s not in QML. The idea is to load a simple HTML file into the WebEngineView, and the HTML file loads the video through an iframe. See https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-videoplayer-example.html.

Comment: No. Its not working with live streams. I check it. Now the compiler begin to show errors(they can be ignored) such as ` :-1: error: /mnt/volume1/main_file_folder/Home/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 4 (>= sh_info of 3)`. Am i missing any system dependencies? I ask that because the build wasn't compiled by me.

Comment: I just installed the WebEngine module using the maintenance tool, ran the above example and everything works fine. You might have to reinstall the module from the maintenance tool. My Qt version is 5.12. Someone filed a bug with your error at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80964, you might want to check it out. Also, playing live streams from YouTube requires propietrary codecs.

Comment: but what about ffmpeg they says something about it too that i couldn't understand

Comment: The page don't leads to a fix it is still unsolved. I don't care about that error because it doesn't anything. Can you explain a little bit about proprietary codecs and how to use it. I am not much clear about them. Should i need to get a licence from the developer?,Thank you for your help.

Comment: After searching all around the web, I came to the conclusion that you _have_ to use the proprietary codecs in order to be able to play live YouTube videos. For videos that are not live, you don't have to do anything. These codecs are disabled by default, and can only be enabled when compiling Qt yourself. The licensing shouldn't be an issue, I think these are free, as they are available in the non-commercial Qt version, however, I'm not a lawyer. FFMPEG is just a cross-platform media player that the WebEngine probably uses.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get is trivial and they already gave you the solution in the other answer, instead my answer is to solve the underlying problem. Can't play youtube videos because chromium (and Qt WebEngine) was not compiled by enabling proprietary codecs. The solution is to recompile Qt WebEngine with that flag enabled.

From the comments it can be seen that the OP is using Qt 5.15.1 so he must follow the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libxtst-dev libxss-dev libdbus-1-dev libevent-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcap-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libnss3-dev libasound2-dev libegl1-mesa-dev gperf bison nodejs
git clone -b 5.15.1 git://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebengine.git
cd qtwebengine
git submodule update --init
/path/of/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake . -- -webengine-proprietary-codecs
make
make install
```

**Note:**  According to the logs shown in the comments `/path/of/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake` in your case is `/mnt/volume1/main_file_folder/Home/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake`

Comment: after running the second command i reboot the computer. Now it's only boot  at cmd mode. How can i revert it? I think there is no grub menu.